# Echo php array value

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, echo

I have the following code that reads the content of a folder

PHP Code:

```
<?
//PHP SCRIPT: getimages.php
header('content-type: application/x-javascript');

//This function gets the file names of all images in the current directory
//and ouputs them as a JavaScript array
function returnimages($dirname="./images") {
     $pattern="(\.jpg$)|(\.png$)|(\.jpeg$)|(\.gif$)"; //valid image extensions
     $files = array();
     $curimage=0;
           if($handle = opendir($dirname)) {
                while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
                     if(eregi($pattern, $file)){ //if this file is a valid image 
//Output it as a JavaScript array element
                   echo 'galleryarray['.$curimage.']="'.$file .'";' . "\n";
             $curimage++;
                    } 
            }

            closedir($handle);
}
        sort($files);
        return($files);
}

echo 'var galleryarray=new Array();' . "\n"; //Define array in JavaScript
returnimages() //Output the array elements containing the image file names

?>
```

which spits out this the following code:

```
var galleryarray = new Array();
galleryarray[0] = "image1.jpg";
galleryarray[1] = "image5.jpg";
galleryarray[2] = "image2.jpg";
galleryarray[3] = "image4.jpg";
galleryarray[4] = "image8.jpg";
galleryarray[5] = "image7.jpg";
galleryarray[6] = "image0.jpg";
galleryarray[7] = "image3.jpg";
galleryarray[8] = "image6.jpg";​
```

Now in my html file I want to echo something like

```
<img src="images/image0.jpg" />
<img src="images/image1.jpg"/>
...
...
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($galleryarray as $img) {
    echo "<img src='images/$img' />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the echo line in the function to this:

```
echo '<img src="images/' . $file . '" />' ;
```

Hope this will help :)

**OR**

Outside the function, use it like this:

```
$images = returnimages(); //will get the array containing the images
foreach($images as $img)
{
  echo '<img src="images/' . $img . '" />';
}
```

Also, you have to include this line inside the if condition in the while loop:

```
$files[] = $file; //insert the file into the array. This array is what we are going to return from the function
```

**Update**

I have tested this code and it's working:

```
    //PHP SCRIPT: getimages.php
    header('content-type: application/x-javascript');

    function returnimages($dirname="./images") {
         $pattern="([^\s]+(\.(?i)(jpg|png|gif|bmp))$)";     //  http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-image-file-extension-with-regular-expression/
         $files = array();
         if($handle = opendir($dirname)) {
            while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
                if(preg_match($pattern, $file)){ //if this file is a valid image 
                    $files[] = $file;
                } 
            }

            closedir($handle);
        }
        //sort($files);         // http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php
        natcasesort($files);    // case insensitive "natural order" algorithm :: http://php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php

        return($files);
    }

    $images = returnimages(); //will get the array containing the images
    foreach($images as $img)
    {
      echo '<img src="images/' . $img . '" />';
    }
```

In my `images` folder, I have put 5 files for testing. And upon running it, it would give the following:

```
<img src="images/a.jpg" />
<img src="images/ba.jpg" />
<img src="images/ca.jpg" />
<img src="images/Copy (3) of a.jpg" />
<img src="images/Copy (4) of a.jpg" />
```

Comment: is there a way to sort the file name alphabetically?

Comment: no i tried sort($file) and sort($files) it didnt work. where should i put them?

Comment: the code works great. how can i print or echo the output in my html file?

Comment: The last 5 lines of code will do the trick. First we are calling the function `returnimages()` and then assigning the array returned by the function into a variable `$images`. This would be an array. The next line, that is the `foreach` loop will iterate through each element in the array. Inside the loop, I'm echoing the images wrapping HTML `img` tags.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this help u

```
$pattern="(\.jpg$)|(\.png$)|(\.jpeg$)|(\.gif$)"; //valid image extensions
           if($handle = opendir("./images")) {
                while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
                     if(eregi($pattern, $file)){ ?>
                   <img src="/images/<?php echo $file;  ?>">
            <?php 
                    } 
            }
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you want to sort image name by value and then show the images. you first need to sort values by using function "asort"

```
    asort($galleryarray);
    foreach ($galleryarray as $key => $val) {
        echo "<img src='images/{$val}'/>"
    }
```

---

if you want to print and array

1. print_r($array); or if you want nicely formatted array then

   echo ''; print_r($array); echo '';
2. use `var_dump($array)` to get more information of the content in the array like datatype and length.
3. you can loop the array using php's foreach(); and get the desired output. more info on foreach in php's documentation website https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php